# How to use external microphone as audio source in Android (Glass)

Tags: android, audio, microphone, aero-glass

I am attempting to use an external microphone as the recording device for an Android Application (that will be ported to Google Glass). The requirement is that the external microphone connect using the micro usb slot on the phone (Google Glass' only port). Would hooking up [Adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Micro-5-pin-USB-MIC-to-USB1-1-USB-2-0-AM-OTG-Adapter-Data-Cord-Cable-ab-/400493917017?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item5d3f4c3359) + [External Mic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004P1BQG2) work by default/work at all?

The overall goal is to pick up better (directional) quality sound from Google Glass than the default microphone. Any tips/thoughts on if the above would work or possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Along the same vein, I'm interested in addressing this in high noise environments (I'm disappointed that the mic is not bone-conductive like the jawbone).  Something like this is interesting [Throat Mic for Moto Sports](http://www.iasuslogistics.com/product/ForTwoWheels/iIAGP3-System.html).

I've heard that there's a bluetooth version in the works.  Perhaps integrating a mic over bluetooth and working it all out with the phone might require KitKat on Glass, or perhaps the Glass App can work this out.